# Berkley DB stl containers in global scope

Tags: c++, scope, containers, global-variables, berkeley-db

I want to open a database and create a container (set) in the global scope so that I can access it from all functions with the following code:

```
DbEnv* penv = open_env(".", 0u, DB_INIT_MPOOL | DB_CREATE);
Db* db = open_db(penv, "test.db", DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0u);
db_set<unsigned long long, ElementHolder<unsigned long long>> testSet(db, penv);
```

This working, if I write this inside the main function (or any other function), but if I place this code in global scope (or even I specify only testSet in the global scope, and then inside any function I open the database and "associate" testSet with it), program crashes with this message: `exited with code -1073741819`

Comment: https://ideone.com/dBR7TO You probably want something like that. Where you have the global variables, and then initialize them in main, call other functions, then close the db and env in main (cleanup) in reverse order of declaration. If it still crashes, check the path of the db and check with a debugger what the stack trace is.

Comment: @Brandon I tried even with vpn, but your link not working

Comment: @Brandon ideone doesn`t work, can you paste code right here please?

Comment: `DbEnv* penv = nullptr;
Db* db = nullptr;
db_set<unsigned long long, ElementHolder<unsigned long long>> test_set;
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   penv = open_env(...);
   open_db(penv, "test.db", ....);
   test_set = {db, penv};
 
 call_other_functions(....);
 call_other_functions(....);
 
 test_set = {};
 close_db(penv, db);
 close_env(penv);
 
   return 0;
}`

Comment: @Brandon ty, I tried this, but it didn`t work. 
Full code: ```#include <db_cxx.h>
#include <dbstl_set.h>
using namespace dbstl;

DbEnv* penv = nullptr;
Db* db = nullptr;
db_set<unsigned long long, ElementHolder<unsigned long long>> test_set;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
 penv = open_env(".", 0u, DB_INIT_MPOOL | DB_CREATE);
 open_db(penv, "test.db", DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0u);
 close_all_dbs();
 close_all_db_envs();
 return 0; 
}```

Errors in debug mode: [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/Lb2CMhhnRhH-)    
But if I place all code in main function, all working correct